# MATLAB and C/C++. How to choose between different C/C++ specifications

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, matlab, g++

I have the following problem compiling a C++ file from a [third-party library](http://code.google.com/p/randomforest-matlab/) in [mex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mex.html) using Visual C++ 2010's compiler (cl.exe).

The compiler complains in multiple lines on a statement like the following::

```
plhs[i] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(nclass, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, 0);
```

with:

> error C2664:
>   'mxCreateNumericMatrix_730' : cannot
>   convert parameter 4 from 'int' to
>   'mxComplexity'

the reason seems to be that `mxCreateNumericMatrix` [takes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mxcreatenumericmatrix.html) an enum type as input argument **4**, called `mxComplexity`, which is [defined](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/apiref/mxcomplexity.html) as `typedef enum mxComplexity {mxREAL=0, mxCOMPLEX};`. In other words, the compiler complains that it can't implicitly convert from **int** to an **enum type**.

Interestingly though, the [library in question](http://code.google.com/p/randomforest-matlab/) is supposed to compile easily without having to change anything in it.

My question therefore is: Instead of adding an explicit cast in every line where this occurs, is there a way of telling **mex**, **cl.exe** (or **gcc**, if I were do to this in Unix), that I want to do a **C-style** type implicit conversion?

**Note 1:** Unfortunately, I don't know in what C++ standard the library was written.

**Note 2:** In case it matters, this is the configuration I have for **mex** (which is set up by MATLAB by default, after running `mex -setup`):

```
 CompilerExecutable: 'cl'
              CompilerFlags: '/c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0 /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /nologo /MD'
          OptimizationFlags: '/O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG'
                 DebugFlags: '/Z7'
           LinkerExecutable: 'link'
                LinkerFlags: '/dll /export:%ENTRYPOINT% /LIBPATH:"%LIBLOC%" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib /MACHINE:X64 kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /nologo /manifest /incremental:NO /implib:"%LIB_NAME%.x" /MAP:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%.map"'
    LinkerOptimizationFlags: ''
           LinkerDebugFlags: '/debug /PDB:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%.pdb"'
```

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but why use a literal 0 instead of mxREAL?

Comment: @Christoffer, it's a good question, but I don't know why the library developer chose to use a literal instead of an enum type. In any case,  I would prefer to not change the source code of the library if I can avoid it.

Comment: @AmV: it seems that they do provide precompiled binaries for both Win32 and 64-bit: http://code.google.com/p/randomforest-matlab/downloads/list

Comment: Oh, this was in the library sources? I must have misread the question, I thought the problem was in the application code.

Comment: @Amro, I am currently using the binaries the authors provide, but I would like to recompile the code to target certain aspects of our hardware architecture.

Comment: @AmV: I just downloaded and compiled the library myself with no problems using VS2010-Pro as compiler on a Windows XP 32-bit machine (I ran the provided `compile_windows.m` file inside MATLAB from both folders)...

Comment: @Amro, I contacted the author a day ago, and he made changes to the source code (latest version in the SVN repository) to avoid the implicit casting. Interestingly, he said that the he was able to compile the old version with no problem using VS-2010 express, so that's why I am keeping the question open. 

Which version did you download? In either case, I'd like to know why this compilation error happens and how to deal with it if you could avoid changing the code.

Comment: @AmV: I downloaded the zip file featured on the download list: `RF_MexStandalone-v0.02.zip` (I did NOT checkout the latest version off the SVN repository)

Comment: @AmV: [UPDATE] I just successfully compiled the latest revision from SVN (r43) which seems to be fixed by the maintainer of the library. It should work for you now: http://code.google.com/p/randomforest-matlab/source/detail?r=43

Comment: @Amro, Thanks for looking into this, but I am still confused . @Alex said below that C++ doesn't allow implicit conversion (confirming my initial guess). Still you said earlier that you managed to compile the older version of the library (the one with implicit casting). The compilation scripts the library comes with use cl.exe (which defaults to C++ when it sees a .Cpp extension), and g++ (as opposed to gcc).

Comment: So, I would like to understand why is it possible to compile a file with implicit castings in C++ and if there is a way of telling cl.exe, g++ or mex to be more tolerant about these syntax differences.

Comment: @AmV: now that I understand the issue, I join you in your confusion... As a simple example: http://pastebin.com/fmJqkdir , this program would compile correctly as C, but will throw a compilation error as C++ (yet somehow `mex` was successful with the older version of the library, at least for me!)

Comment: Finally how did you solve the problem? I got the same errors when compiling some code. I tried "mex -setup C" for compiling in C, but still no working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't allow implicit conversion from int to enum values (*ever*! Not in C++98, 2003, 0x), unlike C, so you need to use the actual enum values for such a parameter.

Or you can compile as C, since the code they wrote isn't C++ (because of the above).

> Note 1: Unfortunately, I don't know in
>   what C++ standard the library was
>   written

It doesn't matter, the C++ standards are backwards compatible, and this code definitely isn't using something new in C++0x, so your compiler is fine. Changing the C++ compilation mode won't allow you to do the aforementioned conversion implicitly.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Interestingly the author of the library claims (http://goo.gl/5TbN1) that he was able to compile it on Windows using Visual C++ express  and on Linux using g++ (in fact, I couldn't get it to compile with gl.exe using the /Tc option, which enforces C compilation, and the make files the library provides for the Linux installation use g++).

Answer (score 1):

First, figure out what language you're using. Are you using C, or are you using C++?

This is one area where they are incompatible.

Comment: The program is written in C++ as far as I can tell. Among other things, the files have extension .cpp and most notably, the Makefile that comes with it for Linux uses `g++`.

Comment: That explains why you can't implicitly convert the types.  The "library in question" claims that you can, presumably, because they assume that you are using C.